# Using f-strings with unicode escapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I've got strings that look something like this:
`a = "testing test<U+00FA>ing <U+00F3>"`

Format will not always be like that, but those unicode characters in brackets will be scattered throughout the code. I want to turn those into the actual unicode characters they represent. I tried this function:

```
def replace_unicode(s):
    uni = re.findall(r'<U\+\w\w\w\w>', s)

    for a in uni:
        s = s.replace(a, f'\u{a[3:7]}')
    return s
```

This successfully finds all of the <U+> unicode strings, but it won't let me put them together to create a unicode escape in this manner.

```
  File "D:/Programming/tests/test.py", line 8
    s = s.replace(a, f'\u{a[3:7]}')
                     ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

How can I create a unicode escape character using an f-string, or via some other method with the information I'm getting from strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an f-string to create an appropriate argument to `int`, whose result the `chr` function can use to produce the desired character.

```
for a in uni:
    s = s.replace(a, chr(int(f'0x{a[3:7]}', base=16)))
```

Comment: Surely you don't need the `0x` since you're specifying the base, and thus you don't need the f string at all.

Answer (score 3):

[chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69380973/4518341) is good, but you don't actually need an f-string. `int(a[3:7], base=16)` works perfectly fine.

Also, it would make a lot more sense to use `re.sub()` instead of `re.findall()` then `str.replace()`. I would also restrict the regex down to just hex digits and group them.

```
import re

def replace_unicode(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r'<U\+([0-9A-F]{4})>')
    return pattern.sub(lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), base=16)), s)

a = "testing test<U+00FA>ing <U+00F3>"
print(replace_unicode(a))  # -> testing testúing ó
```